# How do I fix an Unable to connect to ICE security system : 521 error when creating a Sabre Session Token?

Tags: sabre

Im following the guide at: https://developer.sabre.com/guides/travel-agency/quickstart-guides/get-token to create a Session Token. I have followed the guide and already successfully created a sessionless token.

However, im getting strange error which I have been unable to find any answers to. I know it's not related to credentials as this provides a different error. Here is the request i'm testing in Postman:

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema">
   <soap-env:Header>
      <eb:MessageHeader soap-env:mustUnderstand="1" eb:version="1.0">
               <eb:ConversationId>c88f8e8cb699</eb:ConversationId>
         <eb:From>
            <eb:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">999999</eb:PartyId>
         </eb:From>
         <eb:To>
           <eb:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">123123</eb:PartyId>
         </eb:To>
         <eb:CPAId>XXXX</eb:CPAId>
         <eb:Service eb:type="OTA">SessionCreateRQ</eb:Service>
         <eb:Action>SessionCreateRQ</eb:Action>
         <eb:MessageData>
         <eb:MessageId>1000</eb:MessageId>
         <eb:Timestamp>2024-02-13T16:32:31Z</eb:Timestamp>
         <eb:TimeToLive>2024-02-13T16:32:31Z</eb:TimeToLive>
         </eb:MessageData>
      </eb:MessageHeader>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/utility">
         <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>9999</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>XXXXXXX</wsse:Password>
            <Organization>XXXX</Organization>
            <Domain>DEFAULT</Domain>          
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap-env:Header>
   <soap-env:Body>
      <sws:SessionCreateRQ xmlns:sws="http://webservices.sabre.com" Version="1.0.0"/>
   </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
<soap-env:Body>
        <soap-env:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap-env:Server.SystemFailure</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Unable to connect to ICE security system : 521</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <StackTrace>com.sabre.universalservices.base.exception.ApplicationICEException: errors.authentication.USG_SECURITY_ICE_ERROR</StackTrace>
            </detail>
        </soap-env:Fault>
    </soap-env:Body>
```

Does any one know what causes this error? Also how to fix it please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by credentials which is why its unable to access the ICE security system. Credentials need to be for an IPCC not a PCC.